# Finding the Gaussian random vectors

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution

Let $X,Y, \epsilon$ be independent random variables such that $X,Y\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and
$$\mathbb{P}\{\epsilon=1\}=\frac{1}{2}=\mathbb{P}\{\epsilon=-1\}.$$

Which of the vectors $(\epsilon|X|,\epsilon|Y|),\, (X,\epsilon X),\, (X,\epsilon X+Y)$ are gaussian random vectors (GRV)?

---

My definition of GRV is the following:

A GRV is a two-dimensional random vector $(X_1,X_2)$ such that
for all $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$, $\alpha X_1+\beta X_2$ is normally distributed.

---

I would assume that the first one is a GRV, while the two others aren't. How would one show this? Blindly applying the definition hasn't worked for me.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Well no, but you cannot just assume $\epsilon=1$? For example, $\epsilon |X|$ is normally distributed.

Comment: Nothing to assume; $\epsilon$ takes two values, so there will be two cases for the sum $\epsilon |X|+\epsilon |Y|$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Unless I misunderstand you, I don't agree with you. You cannot just say that "both cases of $\epsilon$ give us non-normal random variables, hence $\epsilon|X|+\epsilon |Y|$ is non-normal."

Comment: You are right, that does not work. Could you show this sum is normal?